# How to connect with wifi during void linux installation

Tags: wifi, system-installation, void-linux

While installing [Void Linux](https://voidlinux.org/), I followed [this](https://wiki.voidlinux.org/Network_Configuration#Wireless_.28default.29) example I'd copied `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` with this command

```
cp /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlo1.conf
```

then edited `wpa_supplicant-wlo1.conf` like this:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
eapol_version=1
fast_reauth=1
update_config=1

# Add your networks here.
network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    wep_key0="MYPASSWORD"
    wep_tx_keyidx=0
    auth_alg=SHARED
}
```

removed the existing `wlo1` in `/run/wpa_supplicant/` and executed the following command:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlo1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlo1.conf
```

and restarted `dhcpcd` by `sv restart dhcpcd`

BUT it didn't work! Then I'd removed this part:

```
network={
        ssid="MYSSID"
        key_mgmt=NONE
        wep_key0="MYPASSWORD"
        wep_tx_keyidx=0
        auth_alg=SHARED
    }
```

from `wpa_supplicant-wlo1.conf` and executed:

```
wpa_passphrase MYSSID MYPASSWORD >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlo1.conf
```

removed the `wlo1` in `/run/wpa_supplicant/` again and executed the same command:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlo1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlo1.conf
```

and restrated `dhcpcd`, it didn't work either!

How to connect?

Comment: This is not answer to your question but I ran into same issue and I tried to remove both "/run/wpa_supplicant & /run/dhcpcd" dirs to get wpa supplicant to work and for some reason that did the trick.

Comment: welcome , you should use the `-B` option to keep `wpa_supplicant` running in background, then run the `dhcpcd` command.

Comment: I've installed it with wired connection. I've used `void-live-x86_64-20181111.iso`, isn't it glibc version? I'd tried to install `nvidia` and got this message `Unable to locate 'nvidia' in repository pool` and no audio!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
wpa_passphrase SSID PASSWORD >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlo1.conf
wpa_supplicant -B -iwlo1 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlo1.conf
```

I don't have to do anything other than typing those two lines.